# Clairaut's Theorem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Clairaut's Theorem: Suppose $f$ is defined on a disk D that contains the point $(a,b)$. If the functions $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are both continuous on D, then
$$f_{xy}(a,b)=f_{yx}(a,b).$$

Now, check this out:

```
f[x_, y_] = If[{x, y} != {0, 0}, x y (x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), 0];
D[f[x, y], x, y] // FullSimplify
D[f[x, y], y, x] // FullSimplify
```

Gives this output:

[image]

Now, is it true that $f_{xy}(0,0)=f_{yx}(0,0)=0$? First, we calculate $f_x$ and $f_y$.

```
D[f[x, y], x] // FullSimplify
D[f[x, y], y] // FullSimplify
```

Which gives this output.

[image]

Now, is it true that $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)$? We will check with the limit definition.

```
Limit[(f[0 + h, 0] - f[0, 0])/h, h -> 0]
Limit[(f[0, 0 + h] - f[0, 0])/h, h -> 0]
```

In both cases, the answer is zero, so we can define $f_x$ and $f_y$ accurately.

```
fx[x_, y] = 
 If[{x, y} != {0, 
    0}, ((x - y) (x + y) (x^4 + 10 x^2 y^2 + y^4))/(x^2 + y^2)^3, 0]
fy[x_, y] = 
 If[{x, y} != {0, 
    0}, ((x - y) (x + y) (x^4 - 10 x^2 y^2 + y^4))/(x^2 + y^2)^3, 0]
```

Now we can calculate $f_{xy}(0,0)$ using the limit definition.

```
Limit[(fx[0, 0 + h] - f[0, 0])/h, h -> 0]
```

This gives an answer of $-1$. And we can calculate $f_{yx}(0,0)$ using the limit definition.

```
Limit[(fy[0 + h, 0] - f[0, 0])/h, h -> 0]
```

This gives an answer of 1. Both of these answers disagree with the opening command:

```
D[f[x, y], x, y] // FullSimplify
D[f[x, y], y, x] // FullSimplify
```

Which gave:

[image]

Which says incorrectly that $f_{xy}(0,0)=f_{yx}(0,0)=0$. However, this doesn't contradict Clairaut's Theorem, because $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are not continuous at (0,0).

Any thoughts?

P.S. By the way, does the word True have the same meaning as Otherwise in these piecewise functions?

Comment: "does the word `True` have the same meaning as Otherwise in these piecewise functions" - yes, it's the default "case"; if none of the other conditions are matched, that is the function applied.

Comment: Anyway: you might want to read [Stan Wagon's treatment](http://books.google.com/books?id=EbVrWLNiub4C&pg=PA130).

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Nice link. That use of MeshFunctions in his example is brand new to me. Haven't seen that before. Very cool. I had already done some writing on this example: [http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/StewartMathematica/chapter14/ClairautTheorem.nb](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/StewartMathematica/chapter14/ClairautTheorem.nb). Also, I've really had a good time with Abdulkadir Hassen's site at [http://users.rowan.edu/~hassen/Math_Rogawski_Calc.htm](http://users.rowan.edu/~hassen/Math_Rogawski_Calc.htm). See chapter 14. Amazing effort.

Comment: In fact, I wanted you to pay attention to the part where he demonstrates through a plot that the derivative is in fact discontinuous, and his use of polar coordinates to highlight that feature.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.Looks like you didn't download and read my notebook?

Comment: I don't have access to a computer at the moment. I'll look into it when I am able.

Comment: Just had a look; pretty okay. You might be interested in `DifferenceDelta[]` if you're showing your students the limits.